# Should self argument be provided explicitly in the calling function

Tags: rust

I was under the assumption that the argument for self can be omitted in the calling function(I've seen many cases where self argument was omitted in the calling function). However, I got the following error (asking me to include an argument for self)

```
error[E0061]: this function takes 1 argument but 0 arguments were supplied
  --> src/main.rs:13:15
   |
13 |     let st1 = St::new();
   |               ^^^^^^^-- an argument of type `St` is missing
   |
note: method defined here
  --> src/main.rs:7:8
   |
7  |     fn new(self)-> St{
   |        ^^^ ----
help: provide the argument
   |
13 |     let st1 = St::new(/* St */);
```

Following is the simple source code:

```
struct St{
    a:i32,
}

impl St{
    fn new(self)-> St{
        St{a:5}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let st1 = St::new();
    println!("st1.a is {}", st1.a);
}
```

I tried running it by supplying the calling function in main with an argument and it works.

Comment: Your `new` should not have `self` as a parameter. In OOP lingo, it's a "constructor" - it produces a `Self` "instance", it doesn't consume one.

Comment: @Luatic I don't think the ctor terminology is constructive: in most OO languages, "this" is created (somehow) before the ctor is called and the ctor modifies it in place. `new` is rather a "factory method".

Comment: @Masklinn It's common in the Rust community to call it a constructor. See e.g. https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that does not make it constructive or helpful

Comment: @Masklinn well, in prototype-based OO, it is not uncommon to be creating "objects" / "tables" yourself in a function which is then called a "constructor" because it "constructs" an object. But indeed, in most class-based OO langs like Java you typically mutate `this`, so this is probably where the confusion stems from.

Comment: @Luatic It absolutely can consume

Comment: @randomranger409 of course it can, but it doesn't make sense in this context. You want a function which gives you a new value. You don't want it to consume an existing value. Why do you add a consumed `self` parameter then? You don't even use the `self` parameter. You could call your `new` function as `let st1 = St::new(St{a: 42});`, but it doesn't make sense - the `St{a: 42}` is just thrown away.

Comment: You can never omit the `self` argument (most of the times it uses dot notation, though). So you must be misremembering. Can you bring an example of compiling code that omits it?

Comment: @Luatic you're right about the fact that I don't need self in the function signature. But I've seen examples where "in the calling function" self argument is omitted, whereas in the function signature there is a self. Also I was under the impression that every function needs a self to be passed. Makes sense in this case to omit it.

Comment: @randomranger409 what you've probably seen is the typical "method call syntax" where a method on a struct is called as `instance.method(...)`. `instance` is then implicitly passed as `self`. This is different from `Struct::method(...)` where you have to pass all parameters, including `self`. I'd recommend you to take a look at [the corresponding chapter in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html) :)

Comment: @Luatic I totally understand it now. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Rust associated functions are similar to, but not identical to, methods from a traditional OOP language. In particular, Rust associated functions may *optionally* take a `self` parameter, which allows calling the method with dot-notation.

However, the emphasis is on the "optionally" part. Only methods which actually need a `self` should take one. When you write a `new` method, that's acting as a constructor. Rust doesn't have any special syntax for constructor-like methods; they're just ordinary functions that construct something. A `new` method doesn't need to take a `self`, because it's going to construct and return one. So rather than

```
impl St {
  fn new(self) -> St {
    St { a: 5 }
  }
}
```

Just remove the `self` and you can call it the way you're planning to.

```
impl St {
  fn new() -> St {
    St { a: 5 }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly also worth noting that even the name `new` is just a convention, there's nothing special about an associated function named "new" and it doesn't get treated differently.

Comment: Doesn't associated functions become methods when they take self? 
https://practice.rs/method.html

Comment: Not really, taking a `self` parameter allows calling with method syntax (`object.method()`) but otherwise it's just as much an associated function as any other. `Object::method(&object)` is as valid as the method syntax if the receiver is `&self`.